# How can I Create Autorun DVD?

Tags: windows, dvd, autorun

My boss ask me to create a Multimedia Autorun DVD that contain our company Video and photo gallery, I want to know which software can help me? what is the best choice, because I don't have enough time, so please gave me the your best suggestion?

Please remember that, I want to create photo and video gallery Autorun DVD

Answer (score 1):

This article on the Microsoft KB may help:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818804

This article is related to .net but you should be able to use this for any project/program.

Answer (score 0):

Autorun is controlled by a small text file in the root of the DVD called [autorun.inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf) which contains, amongst other things, pointers to the icon the DVD should show in Explorer, and the program that should be run upon insertion.

What you use to create the program that gets executed is entirely up to you and should be what you are most comfortable with.

A few things to remember when creating the program:

- It should not require any additional software or libraries to be installed
- It should not require installation itself but run 'in place' from the DVD

Historically a number of popular systems have been used to create autorun software:

- Adobe Shockwave
- Macromedia Director

It is also possible to 'autorun' a web page and create the application entirely in HTML and Javascript.

Comment: how can i convert the webpage to autorun DVD?

Comment: The windows `start` command will open any document in the program it is associated with.  `open=start \path\to\my\page.htm` in the autorun.inf should do it