# How to "autorun" executables from a CD/DVD on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, dvd, autorun, compact-disc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I Create Autorun DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/257379/how-can-i-create-autorun-dvd)

I want my software to run automatically from a CD/DVD with no user interaction whenever the user puts the CD/DVD into the drive. As far as I know autorun should still work with Windows 7, just not for USB drives.

But how?

Let's say I want to start *software.exe*, **how do I configure *autorun.inf* ?** This, doesn't work.

```
[AutoRun]
open=software.exe
```

What is preventing software.exe* from running? How can I run it (automatically)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Create Autorun DVD?](http://superuser.com/questions/257379/how-can-i-create-autorun-dvd) - Specifically see [This Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/257379/how-can-i-create-autorun-dvd/257383#257383) for some help.

Comment: Also note that many companies disable autorun as an added layer of defense against malware.

Comment: BTW: Ensure you haven't disabled AutoRun on your test computer.  And although I'm not 100%, I think the section header is case sensitive, as all examples tend to show it as [autorun] and not [AutoRun].

Comment: Consider whether you really want to do this.  Autorun is a bad feature that opens horribly bad security holes.

Answer (score 1):

Security built into Windows 7 prevents autorun from running.

(The reason why it won't work is becasuse on Windows 7, the only keys available in the *[autorun]* section of **autorun.inf** are *label* and *icon* (except for on DRIVE_CDROM drives). Any other keys in this section will be ignored. Thus only CD and DVD media types can specify an AutoRun task (or affect double-click and right-click behavior).

There is a patch available, [KB971029](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971029) for Windows XP and later, that will change AutoRun functionality to this behaviour.)

Comment: Ok, so what do I have to put in the autorun.inf in order to start xy.exe automatically?

Comment: Its impossible without the patch.  Once you install the patch, then it'll work.  (There is no way to autorun a .exe in windows 7 without the patch.)

Comment: @wizlog: I think you got a few things wrong here. 1. The OP specifically asks for a solution for optical drives, which - as you said yourself - should still work on Windows 7. 2. The patch is intended for Windows XP, Vista and Server 2003 in order to behave like Windows 7 does. You cannot install this patch on Windows 7 nor would it do any good.

Comment: Just to answer the question directly: ***"What is preventing software.exe from running?"***  Answer: Security

Comment: @Dennis Thats right, I'm now wondering if it's possible to autorun an .exe on a CD on Windows 7 after all? That has not been answered so far.